# Returning an average double from two hashmaps using Collectors in java

Tags: java, functional-programming

I have two hashmaps: `busStops` and `busServices`.

Both are a linked to each other in a many-to-many relationship i.e. one bus stop can have many services and one service can have many bus stops.

Hashmap.java - both busStops and busServices are instances of this.

```
class HashMapO<K,V> {
  private HashMap<K,V> map;

  public HashMapO() {
    map = new HashMap<>();
  }

  public void put(K key, V value) {
    map.put(key, value);
  }

  public Optional<V> get(K key) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(map.get(key));
  }

  public Stream<Map.Entry<K,V>> entries() {
    return map.entrySet().stream();
  }
}
```

averageStops.java

```
  public double averageNumberOfBusesPerStop() {
    double results = busStops.entries()
//return a stream of key value entries in busStops' hashmap.

        .filter(x -> x.getValue().getBusServices())
//for each entry, get the value(e.g. the busStop) and return a stream of services for that stop.

        .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble());
//not sure how to implement collector here.
    return results;
  }
```

BusStop.java

```
class BusStop {
  public BusStop(String name){
    this.name = name;
    buses = new HashSet<>();
  }
  public Stream<BusService> getBusServices() {
    return buses.stream();
  }
  public boolean add(BusService bus) {
    return buses.add(bus);
  }
    }
```

I'm looking to find the **average number of buses per stop** and the **bus with the most stop** using Java's collectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has two errors:

- `filter` requires a `boolean` value. Your lambda returns a `Stream`.
- `averagingDouble` requires a `double` value. You didn't even give one.

Assuming you added the `filter` to exclude bus stops with no services, your code would be:

```
double average = busStops.entries()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().getBusServices().anyMatch(x -> true))
    .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(e -> e.getValue().getBusServices().count()));
```

Or:

```
double average = busStops.entries()
    .mapToDouble(e -> e.getValue().getBusServices().count())
    .filter(cnt -> cnt != 0)
    .average();
```

The code would greatly benefit from having access to the underlying `size()` method, so it won't have to stream and count, though I believe Java 9 optimizes that, so `entrySet().stream().count()` actually just calls `size()`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Andreas said above, you can find the the bus(ses) with the most stops using something similar to the following:

```
<Foo, Bar extends Comparable<Bar>> List<Map.Entry<Foo, Bar>>
       findMaxEntries(Map<Foo, Bar> input){
   Map.Entry<Foo, Bar> maxEntry = null;
   for (Map.Entry<Foo, Bar> entry : input.entrySet())
       if (maxEntry == null || entry.getValue().compareTo(maxEntry.getValue()) > 0)
           maxEntry = entry;
   Map.Entry<Foo, Bar> finalMaxEntry = maxEntry;
   return input
           .entrySet()
           .stream()
           .filter(e-> Objects.equals(e.getValue(), finalMaxEntry))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

}

Comment: Thanks, i'm curious, is there a way to do this by Collectors.groupingBy?